# Creating a token from Minime

Tags: tokens

I've tried to git clone https://github.com/Giveth/minime.git, and had to search to find out how to give it a try.  Turns out I had to 'npm install minimetoken' which failed on Windows.  I don't know why.  The logs were not very helpful.

I tried on Linux, cloned the repo, and typed npm install minimetoken.  This appeared to install it in node_modules/minimetoken.  I still can't see how to run it or use it.

Is there a simple step by step guide for trying minime, then cloning a token with minime?

There are no really clear docs on making a token and testing it out as far as I can tell.  Any links appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an ERC20 test token, install metamask extension on Chrome. Change the network to ropsten testnet and goto remix.ethereum.org (solidity IDE). 
Copy and paste the Minime codes you need in the text area and change the token details such as name, supply, symbol etc to your choice. 
Click on click on the "run" tab and then locate and click on "Create". Metamask will pop out, prompting you to pay for gas. Click on submit and wait for the block to be mined and your token is created.